# customized listview comes from database i want click listview means it prints particular itemname

Tags: android, android-layout

I have fetched images and text as listview from database.now on clicking the particular text or image i should print same text.
Eg: if i click the listview of food menu then it should print food menu.if i click list view of catalogue it should print the catalogue  .

```
enter code here
JSONArray json = jArray.getJSONArray("mainmenu");
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainmenulist);
         adapter=new MainMenulist(this, json);
         list.setAdapter(adapter);

Main menu listview
  public class MainMenulist extends BaseAdapter {
protected static Context Context = null;
int i;
String qrimage;
Bitmap bmp, resizedbitmap;
Bitmap[] bmps;
Activity activity = null;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private ImageView[] mImages;
String[] itemimage;
TextView[] tv;
String itemname;
public String[] itemnames;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public MainMenulist(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
    Context = context;
    // inflater =
    // (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.bmps = new Bitmap[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.itemnames = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];

    try {

        for (i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
            qrimage = image.getString("menuimage");
            itemname = image.getString("menuname");
            itemnames[i] = itemname;

            byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 0,
                    qrimageBytes.length);
            int width = 100;
            int height = 100;
            resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height,
                    true);
            bmps[i] = bmp;

            mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
            mImages[i].setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);

            mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);

            // tv[i].setText(itemname);
        }
        System.out.println(itemnames[i]);
        System.out.println(map);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImages.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;

    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainmenulistview, null);

    TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.menutext);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.menuimage);
    image.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);

    text.setText(itemnames[position]);
    text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (itemnames[position].equals("Food Menu")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Context, FoodMenu.class);
                System.out.println("prakash");
                Context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    return vi;

}

  }
```

i can fetch all items in menulistview.java please tell me how to get particular list view click means particular item  prints

Comment: Log your getView method. Is it called ? With wich value of position ? Moreover, you should consider recylcing convertView if it is already created (i.e : if it is not null then reuse the component, don't create a new one).

Comment: how can i put vote for who is answer for me

Comment: i can't understand what ur telling snicolas. shall u explain with my code

Comment: text.setText(itemnames[position]); this line all itemnames append to the text.if i click particular text means it prints particular text i want avoid the below code                                     public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (itemnames[position].equals("Food Menu")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Context, FoodMenu.class);
                System.out.println("prakash");
                Context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check below code

```
text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (itemnames[position].equals("Food Menu")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Context, FoodMenu.class);
            System.out.println("prakash");
            System.out.println(v.getText().toString());
            Context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

Think you want to print name as you suggested at the place of your
`System.out.println` statement

Comment: i am giving manually itemnames[position].equals("Food Menu"). now i want dynamic. which item name i click means it print that itemname

Answer (score 0):

Use the below link which shows a sample app and also how to use custom adapter.including the click events

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/183608/Android-Lists-ListActivity-and-ListView-II-Custom

try below::

```
text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Context, FoodMenu.class);
            System.out.println(itemnames[position]);
            System.out.println(text.getText().toString());
            Context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```